# Mutable Variable is in accessible from closures

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript. Here is my code

```
  ......
var filename, result, user=["a", "b", "c","d"];
for(var p=0;p<user.length;p++)
      {
       filename=userID[p]+'_'+user[p]+'.json';

       fs.readFile(filename, function read(err, data)
       {
           if (err) {throw err;}
           result = data.toString();

            if (result.charAt(result.length-1) === ',')
             result = result.substring(0,result.length-1) + ']}';

          console.log(p+filename+result+"\n\n"); //here

            });

         }
```

In "here" the value of p is always showing the last index, in this case 3 in for all iterations also the filename is the for the last iteration.How can I get the correct value of p in "here". For p my compiler shows "Mutable Variable is in accessible from closures".

Comment: It's happening because `readFile` is asynchronous and by the time `read` is called, `p` has already incremented to `3`. Use a [let binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) (ie `let p = 0`) instead of `var`. Or you could use `user.forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@naomik comment seems right any asynchronous job with in body of loop is always bad idea. because loop will not wait till response.

```
var filename, result, user=["a", "b", "c","d"];
var p=0;
 function readfileUnitil(p)
  {
   filename=userID[p]+'_'+user[p]+'.json';

   fs.readFile(filename,function(err, data)
   {
       if (err) {throw err;}
       result = data.toString();

        if (result.charAt(result.length-1) === ',')
         result = result.substring(0,result.length-1) + ']}';

      console.log(p+filename+result+"\n\n"); //here
        if(p<user.length){
         p++;
         readfileUnitil(p);
        }
        });
   }
 }
```

i do prefer this kind of recursion instead of let variable as this is more readable and memory will not held by browser hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In this case scope of `filename` is `for loop` block, `filename` value have bind to `fs.readFile`. Simple way to fix this, follow the block code

```
var filename, result, user = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (var p = 0; p < user.length; p++) {
    filename = userID[p] + '_' + user[p] + '.json';

    (function(file) {
        fs.readFile(filename, function read(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            result = data.toString();

            if (result.charAt(result.length - 1) === ',')
                result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1) + ']}';

            console.log(p + filename + result + "\n\n"); //here

        });

    })(filename)

}
```